# How do I place a button next to a heading?

Tags: html, css, position

I thought using `float: right;` would fix this, but it makes the button appear outside of the div. How do I solve this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <h1>Title</h1> <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmj734ht/)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The original answer suggested using `inline-block` and `float` to position the elements, but things have moved on since then. A more flexible solution today would be to use `flex`.

```css
#main {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical align the elements to the center */
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto; /* Push this element to the right */
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>Title</h1> <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

#### Old answer

Give your `h1` `display: inline-block` to allow your elements to occupy the same row...

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>Title</h1> <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case I wanted the heading text centered, so I was able to get that by replacing "display: inline-block" with "text-align: center".

Answer (score 16):

Try like this:

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1> Title <button>Button</button></h1> 
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tmj734ht/1/)**

or you can use the `display:inline` so they appear side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Another great option is the flexbox
use like this:

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  display:flex;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can optionally add `justify-content:space-between` like this

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

or choose any other flexbox property

[Here is a comprehensive guide of Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)